# fetching file name using ptrace

Tags: linux, system-calls, ptrace

I'm trying to fetch the filename which gets opened when the `sys_open` system call is invoked, but I am hitting a Segmentation Fault. The system call `sys_open` opens only the first file used and then hits the segmentation fault. How do I resolve this?

The code looks like this:

```
    while(1) {
     wait(&status);
     if(WIFEXITED(status))
         break;
     orig_eax = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                       sb->child, 8 * ORIG_RAX,
                       NULL);
     printf("%l\n", orig_eax);
     if(orig_eax == SYS_open) {
        if(toggle == 0) {
           toggle = 1;
           rdi = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                              sb->child, 8 * RDI,
                              NULL);
           rsi = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                              sb->child, 8 * RSI,
                              NULL);
           rdx = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                              sb->child, 8 * RDX,
                              NULL);
           str = (char *)calloc((rdx+1)
                             , sizeof(char));

           getdata(sb->child, rdi, str, 100);
        }
        else {
           toggle = 0;
        }
     }
  ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, sb->child, NULL, NULL);
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure why  *rdx+1* bytes are being allocated for a string. Can you please explain?

Comment: MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your program doesn't contain everything it needs to compile (including `getdata`, which is where, I suspect, your problem lies). It is not even 100% clear which platform this program was written for.